# ToShortTimeString Rendering 24 Hour

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, culture

I have an issue where running code on my local machine and the server render 2 different results.

The codet that I'm calling is:

```
Dim t as DateTime = Date.Now
t.ToShortTimeString
```

On the server it is rendering as:

> 14:32

And on my local machine it is rendering as

> 2:32 PM (this is what we want it to be)

They are both setup using English as the locale. Is there any other setting on the machine that I should be checking to know what could be wrong?

This is the server language information. It shows that Short Time should be displaying as I'm expecting it to

[image]

Comment: English, ok, but.... what english? in USA English (en-us) the DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern is `h:mm tt` and in UK English (en-gb) is `HH:mm`. Maybe the culture in local and in server differ in that way? If you need to show the time always with this format, why don't use `DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")` ?

Comment: @frikinside Screenshot shows that it's English US

Comment: OMG! You're right! I'm blind! Sorry about that, any way, can you check that `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` are correct in the execution of the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Region and Language** settings for Windows are different per user.  You need to determine the user account under which the web site is running and check that user's settings.

If necessary, you can use the **Administrative** tab to copy the settings the system accounts.   [This article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apply-regional-language-settings-reserved-accounts#1TC=windows-7) describes, in detail, how to do that.

As others have mentioned, though, if you always want the time to be formatted in a particular way, you should not use the `ToShortTimeString` method.  You should use one of the overrides of the `ToString` method to force the exact formatting that you desire, for instance:

```
t.ToString("hh:mm tt")
```